# HELP! How do I set mesa 3.3 as my opengl version string

Tags: opengl, mesa

All I want to do in play a new game I bought on steam. When I run it, it gives me this error...

```
Detected OpenGL version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.1-devel
Required OpenGL version: 3.3
Please update your display driver.
```

I have tried a bunch of things this last week and I just don't understand, then when I go to check my version it says I still have mesa 3.0 but
my max core version profile 3.3 which is what I need.

```
laptop:~$  glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.1.0-devel
laptop:~$ glxinfo | grep core
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.1.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to force the OpenGL version string to 3.3 using the following prefix prior to the command used to launch your game:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 command
```

For steam, you should be able to add this as a launch option (see [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1040-JWMT-2947)).

However, there is no guarantee that your game will run without issues if it does launch using this method. It also looks like you're using a development version of Mesa which may also not be stable.

My answer in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886548/making-sense-of-glxinfo-opengl-versions) may help explain the different Mesa versions listed by glxinfo.

Comment: Im sorry, Im a bit new to Linux but how do you open an app in steam with a command?

Comment: I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: So i figured out how to run the game via terminal, but this happend. ill just copy and paste it.

Comment: laptop:~$ MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 command
laptop:~$ steam steam://rungameid/239140
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)

Comment: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(148479

Comment: m)/version(1484790260)
Installin** (steam:4826): WARNING **: Unknown device type 14

** (steam:4826): WARNING **: Could not create object for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2: unknown object type

** (steam:4826): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'secondaries'

** (steam:4826): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:4826): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:4826): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:4826): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

Comment: Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 384x256, total string texture memory is 442.37 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
roaming config store loaded successfully - 573 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
ExecCommandLine:

Comment: and a lot more, then just said again, unsupported version of open gl

Comment: You needed to replace "command" with the command to launch your program (for example `MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 glxinfo`). If you're going to launch the game as you have above, try exporting the override first like this `export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3`, press return and then launch your game using the command as you have above.

Comment: i did both ways and this came up along with many other things

Comment: success = yes
assert_20170302224037_1.dmp[4066]: response: CrashID=bp-fc55c7a7-50ae-4c2f-81d1-b19a62170302
assert_20170302224037_1.dmp[4066]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20170302224037_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-fc55c7a7-50ae-4c2f-81d1-b19a62170302''