# Updating OpenGL from version 3.0 to latest 4.5

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, opengl, mesa

I am trying to update my OpenGL driver to the latest version. I have tried the following ppas:

```
ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
ppa:eek:ibaf/graphics-drivers
ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
```

So far nothing works. Is there any solution for this?

Output of glxinfo | grep OpenGL

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 405 (Braswell) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.2.0-devel - padoka PPA
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.0-devel - padoka PPA
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 17.2.0-devel - padoka PPA
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: Absolutely the same problem with Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) .

Comment: Did you see the comment about the OpenGL string on https://askubuntu.com/questions/886548/making-sense-of-glxinfo-opengl-versions?rq=1  ? According to the answer, "Note the last part "OpenGL 4.5 is only available if requested at context creation because compatibility contexts are not supported". Therefore, I think the "OpenGL version string" is the supported version for a "compatibility" profile context (or in other words, for support of any deprecated feature prior to version 3.0)." To my understanding, 3.0 is a fallback mode (for apps that do not request >3.0).

Comment: @MaliRemorker Yeah, I ,managed to figure it out after a bit of digging.

Comment: @MaliRemorker Emil Zahariev seems to consider this question answered by your information and therefore in a sense it may be a duplicate of your question. Do  you think this question needs a better answer? Are you still looking for help relating to this yourself?

Comment: @Zanna The answer to the question is in one of two things. Either the kernel version must be above 4.11.x or that the lines from the output of glxinfo are slightly misleading and that it is using a compatibility mode. As such after a kernel update there might be a change. However there is the possibility that the graphics card does not support that version. Hereis the link to the thread:  http://archive.is/Mc7dy

Comment: @Zanna Yes I think the question needs a better answer because, while  both the OP and I, after upgrading to Mesa > v17, have our "core profile" OpenGL versions at 4.5, the matter of fact is that the games which require OpenGL >3 , or >4 (such as Victor Vran and DIvinity Original Sin) still complain that the card is not supporting OpenGL 3.2 (VV) , or 4.0 (D:OS) . For me, the question is now if the games themselves have implemented OpenGL detection in a lousy way, or Intel drivers still do not support OpenGL >3.0 .

Answer (score 1):

I own a laptop with Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2). I ran into same issue, wasn't able to solve with the given solution.So, I tried doing following things and it helped.

On running command:

```
glxinfo|grep OpenGL
```

You'll be getting **`core profile version string`** output, which will determine the max to which you can clamp your version of opengl. For me it was 4.5 so next I ran the following command :

```
export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.5
```

You can write your required version within your available range. Post this you can check the updated version with this command:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

Once you can see that your version has been changed you can export it in your bashrc with the following command:

```
echo 'export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.5' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but answering if anyone stumble upon this.

I had Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4. I had the problem of [glxinfo showing incorrect version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285502/glxinfo-shows-different-versions-in-the-same-machine-on-different-runs). Most of the time, OpenGL version was shown to be 3.3. I had to update my kernel to 4.15 and the problem got fixed. I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Restarted the system, now I have OpenGL 4.5:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```