# g++ uses OpenGL 3.0 but I have 4.5

Tags: application-development, gcc, opengl, shared-library, g++

In the c++ code I put the line

```
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
```

and it outputs

```
3.0 Mesa 17.3.0-devel
```

although

```
$ glxinfo | grep "version"
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.3.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.3.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 17.3.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

how do I tell g++ that I want to use 4.5

---

**Edit:**

*Okay so I just followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859501/learning-opengl-in-ubuntu) to install an OpenGL development environment.*

I use these headers:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
```

and I use g++ to compile, here's the command:

```
g++ -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW example.cpp -o example && ./example
```

...I ran `glxgears -info` and it ran fine:

```
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
GL_RENDERER   = Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
GL_VERSION    = 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7
GL_VENDOR     = Intel Open Source Technology Center
GL_EXTENSIONS = GL_ARB_multisample GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_copy_texture GL_EXT_polygon_offset GL_EXT_subtexture GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_texture GL_EXT_texture3D GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_multitexture GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_INGR_blend_func_separate GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_S3_s3tc GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_MESA_window_pos GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_window_pos GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_APPLE_packed_pixels GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ATI_draw_buffers GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_read_format GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_APPLE_object_purgeable GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_timer_query GL_OES_EGL_image GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_NV_conditional_render GL_AMD_conservative_depth GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_shader_precision GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_compute_shader GL_ARB_copy_image GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_ARB_shader_image_size GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_ARB_stencil_texturing GL_ARB_texture_query_levels GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_robustness GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_internalformat_query2 GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_query_buffer_object GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_texture_stencil8 GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_ARB_clip_control GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted GL_ARB_cull_distance GL_ARB_derivative_control GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples GL_ARB_texture_barrier GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops GL_ARB_shader_clock GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions 
VisualID 210, 0xd2
```

it says 3.0.

...I couldn't find any simple guide to just make an OpenGL 4.5 development environment. Probably [this](https://bcmpinc.wordpress.com/2015/08/18/creating-an-opengl-4-5-context-using-sdl2-and-glad/) is one of the simplest but it's still too complicated for me. I'm fairly new to c++ and "make files".

...you can also see [my question on linuxquestions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5767337), it may have some information, but it's not to the point because at first I didn't know where the problem was.

Comment: Maybe related: [Making sense of glxinfo OpenGL versions](https://askubuntu.com/a/886945/178692)

Comment: It says I have to "request it", how do I do that?

Comment: I think you ARE using 4.5.  Note in your output Max core profile version: 4.5

Comment: okay but in my C code, when I print the version I get `3.0 Mesa`. It is falling back or something. @pauljohn32

Answer (score 2):

The answer is going to involve "which devel packages do you have?" and do you have more than one shared library?

I don't really think there is a mismatch in your case, though. I think you are mis-reading the output.  What you see here is that the "core profile" version is different from the "shading profile" version number.  But the glxgears is also on Open GL version string 3.0.

Ask differently for the version information

```
$ glxgears -info
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
GL_RENDERER   = Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)
GL_VERSION    = 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7
GL_VENDOR     = Intel Open Source Technology Center
```

If you keep thinking there is trouble, we need details.  Do you have a Makefile?  Where does it come from?  Usually in larger compiles, there is a ./configure program that checks which version of opengl is to be used.

Or show us your g++ compile command and the output from the terminal. Because the g++ command you type will have include and linking statements, -L ....  These things control which library is put to use. If your command does not make any special features, you are taking whatever is considered default in your system.  Often, that is the old one, not the new one.

Even if glxgears is linked to a newer GL, and I don't think yours is, it might be your devel packages are for an older version. The version of the devel package, not the runtime package, will determine what version is used.

Like you, I have mesa supplying the opengl support,

You can ask your glxgears program which shared library it is using, but that does not necessarily same devel version you have installed in your computer. Many users don't have devel packages installed at all, since the programs are compiled "over there" in the package production system and each PC is only required to have the runtime part.