# glxinfo for OpenGL missing info

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, opengl

I am trying to develop code for OpenGL 2.0, but for some reason `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"` only gives me `OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 17.0.1)`.

I saw some answers like [Making sense of glxinfo OpenGL versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886548/making-sense-of-glxinfo-opengl-versions) saying that I should look at the `OpenGL core` but I don't have that info in my `glxinfo` output.

Full output: https://pastebin.com/Up6bwpq5

- I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.
- Tesla K40 (and same problem with V100 on other servers).
- New nvidia drivers (390.46).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Note these three lines:

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.9, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 17.0.1)
```

Are you sure you have the proper NVIDIA driver installed? I ask because OpenGL on your system is currently being provided with software fallback. The driver for your GPU and OS is here: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/132546/en-us

Comment: Yes, this is my installed driver.

Comment: Also I noticed the: client glx vendor string: SGI line, don't know how to fix it.

Comment: And noticed that direct rendering is NO.

Comment: So I guess now the question is: How do I set the OpenGL vendor to be nvidia...